# visual studio mvc src file path in controller

Tags: html, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I want to generate a html page in controller, and pass it to view to display.
In the controller, I have a code as
XElement LetterHead = new XElement("iframe", new XAttribute("src", "/invoice/letterheader.html"));

When I run the project in VS, the view returns 404, said the resource cannot be found. and said Requested URL: /invoice/letterheader.html

Actually, I placed the file under views\invoice and views\invoice\invoice

So how can I solve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Relative path by giving ~ symbol in the URL

```
XElement LetterHead = new XElement("iframe", new XAttribute("src", "~/invoice/letterheader.html"));
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping. I tried, the error message was 404 again, and said the Requested URL is http://localhost:54948/Invoice/~/invoice/letterheader.html

Comment: then remove the ~ symbol and Invoice from the URL